# Icinga2 no icinga instance writing to the IDO

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi3, icinga2

I'm trying to set up Icinga 2 on my Raspberry Pi 3, but the installation is just not really working. I tried different solutions etc. but nothing really seems to fit.

I mainly followed [this](https://www.4b42.com/support/kb/5649d075b9d15-Icinga-Web-2-Installation-unter-Debian-8-Jessie-9-Stretch) tutorial (it's german), but i also tried a few other ones...

Everything works fine, until i get to the "Monitoring IDO Ressource".

The Page looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnvWO.png

Error: There is currently no Icinga instance writing to the IDO. Make sure that an Icinga instance is configured and can write to the IDO.

My /etc/icinga2/features-enabled/ido-mysql.conf looks like this:

```
/**
 * The db_ido_mysql library implements IDO functionality
 * for MySQL.
 */

library "db_ido_mysql"

object IdoMysqlConnection "ido-mysql" {
  user = "root",
  password = "censored",
  host = "localhost",
  database = "icinga_ido"
}
```

And I imported the database-structure with this:

```
mysql -u root -p icinga_ido < /usr/share/icinga2-ido-mysql/schema/mysql.sql
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you make sure icinga2 running? 

Try to check: 

    systemctl status icinga2 

Or
    service icinga2 status

Comment: You need to restart icinga2 to make it work, e.g. `sudo service icinga2 restart`, or just reboot.

Answer (score 0):

shame noone has replied you yet. This worked for me:

```
sudo su

icinga2 feature enable ido-mysql

systemctl restart icinga2
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).